# Android resource vs hardcoding

Tags: android, resources

I know using a resource is good for redundant uses like any label that is generic across a platforms application but are there any other benefits to using a resource instead of hard coding?

for instance I have a button that is only in one view, is there a benefit to using a string resource for the buttons text even if it is one button that is only in one place in the entire app?

Otherwise I feel like its easier to go in to the one specific view to find the button and change the text if i need to rather then scrolling through an entire resource file to find one string resource.

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one reason for using `strings.xml` than hardcode it. Please read the [localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) documentation. It allows you to easily translate text into many languages as you provide.

Comment: I'm just adding, you can do what you want. Doesn't mean you'll have a quality app at the end (or even one worth using).